# How to install unfloding maps library to VS code

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a project that requires the use of unfolding maps. but I am not able to install its library in VS code.

Comment: Is this the Java library? How is it related to VS?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman  i am working on a java project that implements the unfolding maps as runs in an applet but first I need to add it tot the libraraues

Comment: You need to build a bridge between Java and C#. Do I understand correctly?